# How to make find return the target of a symbolic link in hpux?

Tags: unix, find, system-administration, hp-ux

I want to execute the find command but I want it to return the target instead of the symbolic link itselft.

Is that possible to do in HP-UX?

For example, with:

`security -> /dev/vg_irp_ist/rlv_IRP1_security`

I want to return `/dev/vg_irp_ist/rlv_IRP1_security` and not `security`.

Comment: Try `find -L`. From man page, `-L Follow symbolic links`

Comment: it gives the information from the target but the displayed name is still the symbolic link.

Comment: Uhms, you may need to move the question to [su].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/ksh
 name=$(find /path/to/dir -type l -name whatever -exec ls -l {} \; |awk -F '>' '{print $2}')
```

HPUX does not have a readlink command.  If you have GNU coreutils installed then use readlink.  Otherwise you are stuck with the above.

This is the backwrds version - given the actual filename look thru links to find it.  BEWARE of relative paths in links: i.e., `../../foo/filename`

```
export filename="xz.exe"
find . -type l -exec ls -l {} \; | 
     awk '{print $(NF)}') | grep -q "$filename" && echo $val
```

Comment: I want to find by the name of the target of the symbolic link and not by the name of the symbolic link itself, do you know how can I change that?